# Display GPS location from phone on website

Tags: php, html, iphone

My client has requested the ability to show the GPS location from a phone on their website (google maps). I realise that it requires some functionality to be installed on the phone side to send the GPS coordinates.

Does anyone know which way to go on this issue? Any finished products one can use?

Thanks.

Comment: Downvote, why? I posted it on Webmasters because it's not a code issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the coordinates, use `navigator.geolocation`, which should be supported well on mobile browsers; demo: http://www.bytelevelbooks.com/code/javascript/geolocation.html

This is of course just the start. It then depends on your application how you use the coordinates. In any case, you should be prepared to great variation in precision, ranging from kilometers to meters. Whether the coordinates are based on GPS or something else surely affects the precision, and is affected by the device and especially its settings and its physical location.

Comment: That's helpful, but the person that will use it is not very technology-savvy, and I have no budget to start coding my own application. I am looking for an app or way able to grab the gps coordinates and either go to a certain url to post them or update an sql server.

Comment: Okay I thought about it some more, and I could make a bookmark that the person click on, going to a certain website. That would work I think. Thanks, I'll read up on how to maximize accuracy and so on.